# How do you error check a prompt box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to make sure a user enters a value for the name and doesn't just leave it blank. I have a driver that calls the function and returns the name to a variable.

I've tried

```
if (name == null || name == "") {
        getName();
    }
```

both in the function and below the function call in the driver. I've also tried a while loop in both places. The If statement in the driver let me get by the prompt if I hit okay twice and even if I put a name in on the second time it wouldn't store it. The while loop wouldn't break even after I put a name in.

If this isn't enough code to tell just let me know.

```
function driver(){
var retName = getName();
}
```

```
function getName(){
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    return name;
```

I want the prompt to say please enter a valid name or at least just not let a user past until they enter something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `while` loop:

```js
var name = prompt("Enter your name:");
while (name == null && name == "") {
  name = prompt("Enter your name:");
}
console.log("Valid name!");
console.log(name);
```

Note that the above does not deal with a whitespace-only name - so use `trim` too:

```js
var name = prompt("Enter your name:");
while (name == null && name.trim() == "") {
  name = prompt("Enter your name:");
}
console.log("Valid name!");
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Buddy your code doesnot work as expected. If you click cancel it will log `"Valid name!"`. Try putting `&&` in ur `while` condition.

Comment: Oh yes @MaheerAli, sorry, I fixed it now

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `do/while` loop:

```js
let name;
do {
  name = prompt('Enter your name');
} while (!name);
console.log(name);
```

Comment: do/while is prefect in this case.+1. and _`prompt` will always return a string_ is wrong. If its canceled it returns `null`